# How to create borders in bootstrap when div is 0 height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Twitter-Bootstrap, I have a section of a page that includes a sidebar (which does not take up the whole page, just spans down to the bottom of this section). I have several sections to the right of the sidebar, each of which contain an image on one side, some text on the other, and require a bottom-border.

I'm having trouble with the bottom-border. Since each section is contained in a div, and everything's floated using Bootstrap columns, the divs are 0 height and the borders all float to the top.

EDITED for clarification: I need two distinct columns in this section - a left-hand one (spanning 3 columns) that contains only the sidebar (and takes up the 3 columns all the way to the bottom, leaving blank space after the list), and one (spanning the remaining 9 columns) that contains the story-sections but that stays on the right-hand side of the page.

EDITED to include image (grey lines are included for reference and will not show up on the page, black lines are the borders I'm trying to apply) [image: two-column layout]

Attempted solutions:

- Bottom-border on individual elements: I need one solid line across the bottom of each section, so I can't apply bottom-border to both the image and the text.
- Clearfix: Since I have this sidebar, I can't use a clearfix, because it pushes everything down past the sidebar.
- Overflow: Using overflow causes the images to shrink (which I don't quite understand, but it doesn't help with the border either).

How can I create bottom borders for each of these sections?

```
    <section class="stories">
      <div class="container">
        <h2>Section header</h2>
        <div class="col-sm-3 sidebar">
            <h6>list of stories</h6>
            <ul>
                <li>list-item</li>
                <li>list-item</li>
                <li>list-item</li>
                <li>list-item</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <section class="story-section">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/330x220">
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h6>keyword</h6>
                <h3>Header of section</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eleifend dictum neque sed laoreet ...</p>

            </div>

        </section>

// (there are three more sections with the same class of "story-sections", plus other code on the page, but I've tried to simplify it as much as possible here.) 

      </div>
    </section>
```

css:

```
html, body {
        height: 100vh; 
      }

      .stories {

        .sidebar {
          height: 100vh; 
        }

        .story-section {
          border-bottom: 1px solid $grey; 
        }
      }
```

I'm still fairly new with Bootstrap, so there may be a very simple solution, but I haven't been able to track it down. Any help is very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to have a sidebar with 3 columns + a left section with the remaining 9 columns, then you need to set `col-*-9` in your `story-section`

**Note:** in bootstrap, you need to have `.row` right below `.container` or between nested `col-*`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
.sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightblue
}
.story-section {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
img {
  margin-top: 10px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="stories">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h2>Section header</h2>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 sidebar">
        <h6>list of stories</h6>
        <ul>
          <li>list-item</li>
          <li>list-item</li>
          <li>list-item</li>
          <li>list-item</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <section class="story-section col-xs-9 col-sm-9">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/330x220">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
            <h6>keyword</h6>
            <h3>Header of section</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eleifend dictum neque sed laoreet ...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="story-section col-xs-9 col-sm-9">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/330x220">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
            <h6>keyword</h6>
            <h3>Header of section</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eleifend dictum neque sed laoreet ...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The problem that I'm running into with using a clearfix is that I need the section on the right to align with the section on the left, so it doesn't bounce all the way down past the sidebar's end (I'll edit my question to clarify this).

Comment: Argh, thank you for all the help, @dippas, but applying col-sm-3 causes the images to shrink. I was only able to get the sidebar to take up the entire column (and not shrink the images) by giving the sidebar class a height of 100vh. Any other thoughts? (I did add a div for the row class - thanks for catching that!)

Comment: you already had `col-sm-3` in same div as `sidebar`. can you show me a layout (draw/image) of what you want, with a clear explanation? because what I understood is you want a grid layout of 3 + 9 columns (sum 12), and then inside that section with 9 width column you want to have nested columns in a grid layout 3 + 6

Comment: Sorry, typo - I meant col-sm-9; applying it around the story-section causes the images to shrink. I added an image to the original question for your reference. I got some off-line help which built on your suggestions above (we've added overflow: hidden to the images and given them a height of 100%), but they still tend to get very skinny before the mobile break-point, which wouldn't be ideal if I needed square images.

Comment: Sorry I replied to you and edited the answer when I was already too sleepy, see the edited answer now please

Comment: Yes, this looks great! It'll require a little more fiddling on the mobile side, but that part should be a snap. Thank you!